# Keep the role even if the user leaves discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I made a discord bot and when I type `?s mute @user` they mute the user by adding `Muted` role but when the muted user leaves the `Muted` role get's removed so what should I do. Thank you

**Also**

When I user is muted and leaves the server, there's an Unknown Member error

Comment: You need to use database/json file to record user was muted and when they rejoin the server check if they are muted. If yes - give them muted role! Event you need: ```client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
 // code..
});```

Comment: More like a database, a JSON file would be more of a temporary solution or for testing. But since the amount of data can grow quickly, a database is definitely recommended

Comment: I used **MongoDb** for my bot. The data is stored in a JSON like format and not that complicated to implement into your bot

Comment: Yea, MongoDB is very good for newbies in programming, and also there is MongoDB Atlas which can be useful

Comment: also, when I user is muted and leaves the server, there's an `Unknown Member` error

Comment: how will I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use a database. **MongoDb** is a good choice for this purpose. But there are also many others that are easy to install and use. Just have a look around on the internet. At least for MongoDb there are many tutorials how to implement it into your Discord bot (It's not really complicated).

Once you have that, every time you mute someone for example, you have to store that role assignment in the database. Query if a new user was already on the server and had the muted role, you should do that for every new member. You should do this query in the event "guildMemberAdd". In the event "guildMemberRemove" (or directly when assigning the role) you can then save important role assignments.

It sounds like a lot of work, but once you figure out how to use the database of your choice, it's a quick fix.

Comment: Also I recommend watching [this](https://youtu.be/2otiIRSmZII) guide because it's really good and easy to understand

Comment: also, when I user is muted and leaves the server, there's an Unknown Member error

Comment: how will I solve it?

Comment: @AryaAnish you should create a new post for that, describing the error and providing some code

Comment: ok, but thank for the answer

Comment: Glad I could help :)